# Can't set Latvia as my location (not in the list)

Tags: xbox-one

Xbox one s. Just updated. There is no Latvian language in the list, so I set the English language. When choosing the location, Latvia is not there. And many others aren't there.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely not supported.  There are a finite amount of languages and locales that the Xbox One supports.

[This article](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/console/dashboard-or-hub-in-another-language) shows the languages supported.  Latvian is not on there.  Note that even though the article is in reference to Xbox 360, the section with the table for the languages is in regards to Xbox Live.

Comment: Language was not the problem. The problem was that I couldn't register my mastercard because I couldn't register my postal code because my region was set to UK because Latvia was not in the list.

Comment: You did not mention that at all.  Either way, this should still answer your question.

Comment: On the xbox.com page the list of countries was the same as on the xbox itself, however if you scroll down, you can press on a link "show the full list" and wow - Latvia shows up.

Comment: It doesn't help, sorry. Thank you for help anyway.

Comment: If it was [this page](https://forums.xbox.com/Shell/ChangeLocale#!), thats only to change the language display for the Xbox website.